# Using docker watch feature for CI/CD

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm interested in the "experimental" docker compose watch feature: [[1]](https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/) [[2]](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-compose-experiment-sync-files-and-automatically-rebuild-services-with-watch-mode/).

The two actions available are "sync" and "rebuild" (which is actually rebuild + restart).

I need this for continuous deployment: all I want is docker to detect that I've changed the `.env` or `docker-compose.yml` file (by updating the image version to be pulled) - and to restart the container. No rebuilding is necessary, as I'm not building the image in the first place but rather pulling it from a docker registry.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried many things, and it does not seem possible to update/restart the containers when modifying either `.env` or `docker-compose.yml`. For some reason, changing these files restarts the container, but does not honor the changes.

**However**, you **can** achieve what you want, but instead of modifying `.env` or `docker-compose.yml`, it requires defining an intermediate `Dockerfile` and make changes to that file directly. To me, it's even easier because all changes are localized to that `Dockerfile`. And you can define the following in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: ./myapp
    x-develop:
      watch:
        - action: rebuild
          path: ./myapp/Dockerfile
```

Anyway, here's an example below with [`envoyproxy/envoy` image from DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/envoyproxy/envoy).

#### Example

With the following directory structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── envoy
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── envoy.yaml # it does not matter, it's just a dummy config file
```

And the following files:

- `envoy/Dockerfile`

```
FROM    envoyproxy/envoy:v1.27.0

ENV     ENVOY_UID=1234
```

- `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  envoy:
    build:
      context: ./envoy
    ports:
      - "9901:9901"
    volumes:
      - ./envoy/envoy.yaml:/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
    x-develop:
      watch:
        - action: rebuild
          path: ./envoy/Dockerfile
```

Any changes to `envoy/Dockerfile` you've asked in your question, like:

- updating the image (`FROM` directive): equivalent of changing the image in `docker-compose.yml` in your question
- updating/adding/removing an environment variable (`ENV` directive): equivalent of changing the `.env` in your question

will trigger a rebuild of the image, and restart with the new values.

You can test it works by doing:

```bash
$ docker compose up -d 2>/dev/null

$ docker compose alpha watch
```

And in another window:

```bash
$ # check envoy version (matches the version in Dockerfile)
$ curl -s http://localhost:9901/server_info | jq -r .version | cut -d / -f 2
1.27.0

$ # check ENVOY_UID env var
$ docker inspect 76803907-using-docker-watch-feature-for-ci-cd-envoy | jq -r '.[0].Config.Env' | grep 'ENVOY_UID'
  "ENVOY_UID=1234"

$ # make some changes (image version, env var)
$ sed -i -e 's/v1.27.0/v1.21.0/' -e 's/ENVOY_UID=1234/ENVOY_UID=5678/' envoy/Dockerfile

$ # wait a few seconds while docker compose is restarting the container...
$ sleep 5

$ # check envoy version has been updated!
$ curl -s http://localhost:9901/server_info | jq -r .version | cut -d / -f 2
1.21.0

$ # check ENVOY_UID env var has been updated!
$ docker inspect 76803907-using-docker-watch-feature-for-ci-cd-envoy | jq -r '.[0].Config.Env' | grep 'ENVOY_UID'
  "ENVOY_UID=5678"
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for looking into it. I think this is too heavy for a watch feature that simply bumps a version for auto-redeployment in ci/cd. But it's a valid workaround, and the watch feature is still experimental after all. I guess this is fine for now. Personally I'm using watchtower until the watch feature is improved.

Comment: Are you doing it this way?

Comment: Until now, I've only used the watch feature to rebuild when a **source** file is updated, not the `.env` files or `docker-compose.yml`, so that worked fine! I made this answer just for you because your question was interesting haha. But, if I had to do it, that's what I would do :) To be fair, defining an intermediate `Dockerfile` is not _so_ bad, while I understand it can add some complexity. Maybe you can file an issue asking for the feature you ask on https://github.com/docker/compose/issues?

Comment: I actually did mention this in the issue tracking the [compose spec](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/pull/253#issuecomment-1658167392) for this.